# Redux can not push an object into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux, push

I am trying to learn redux and I am facing a problem to push multiple objects into `initialState` which is an array. I tried the `push()` method, but this is not working. I get submitter value to my `action.payload` which is an object.

reducer function:

```js
import { NEWBOOK, DELETEBOOK } from "./actionTypes"

const initialState = [{}]

console.log(typeof(initialState))

const bookingReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEWBOOK:
      return {
        ...state,
        stae: action.payload,
      }

    case DELETEBOOK:
      return { ...state }

    default:
      return { state }
  }
}

export default bookingReducer
```

dispatch data:

```
const booked = useSelector((state) => state);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const newBookDisp = (value) => {
  dispatch(newBook(value));
}

console.log(booked);
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState([]);
const handleOnChange = e => {
  const field = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    const newInputData = { ...inputData };
    newInputData[field] = value;
    setInputData(newInputData);
}
  
const submitBook = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked on submit button.')
  const from = inputData.from;
  const to = inputData.to;
  const date = inputData.date;
  const ticketclassName = inputData.ticketclassName;
  const guests = inputData.guests;
  const id = parseInt(booked.state.length) + 1;

  const allData = { from, to, date, ticketclassName, guests, id }  
}
```

Comment: why your `initialState` is an array while it must be an `object`!?

Comment: @AbbasBagheri, I want to add multiple objects inside an array. I got object from the form submission and want to put it inside this array.

Comment: there is no reason to use array instead of object, it is always better to create  initialState with object

Comment: @AbbasBagheri There's no requirement for any state to be an object, arrays are perfectly valid as a state value. What data structure is used depends largely on the data that needs to be stored and how it's consumed.

Comment: It is easier to access properties in objects.

Comment: I have tried it with object, can you please give me your explanation in code.?

Answer (score 3):

If the book state is an array the initial state should probably be an empty array. You can then shallow copy the array and append the new data to it.

When you want to delete a book, e.g. remove from the array, use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove the specific element(s).

Also, the default case should just return the current/existing state as-is and ***not*** create a new object reference. This way it won't unnecessarily trigger any component rerenders if it wasn't updated.

```js
const initialState = [];

const bookingReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEWBOOK:
      return state.concat(action.payload);
      // or
      return [...state, action.payload];

    case DELETEBOOK:
      return state.filter(/* filter condition callback */);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

### Running Demo

[image: Edit redux-can-not-push-an-object-into-an-array]

If you *really* want to use `Array.prototype.push` then it would done similar to this:

```js
case NEWBOOK:
  const newState = state.slice(); // shallow copy
  newState.push(action.payload);  // update copy
  return newState;                // return copy
```

This is because the `push` method mutates the array it operates over.

Comment: I have used your ans, but an error occurs, `state.slice is not a function`

Comment: and for the first code(return [...state, action.payload];), the error is `state is not iterable`

Comment: @Hosen If you correctly maintain the state invariant of being an array it *should* be a valid function. If `state` is an array then it is also iterable. Are you mutating the state object elsewhere? Are there more reducer cases?

Comment: there is two cases, one is for insert and other is for delete from this array, and I have declared an array,  I am doing this in my dismatch`const allData = {from, to, date, ticketclassName,guests,id}

newBookDisp(allData);`

Comment: @Hosen So long as `state` is always an array, using array methods will always work. If you are still having issue think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of the code you are working with that we could take a look at live?

Comment: can you please check it.? https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-fire-x3vvj5

Comment: @Hosen Your default reducer case was mutating the invariant, returning an object with a `state` property instead of returning an array, e.g. ***the*** state that ***is*** the array. I *did* sort of point this out in my initial answer. 

Answer (score 0):

Running example:

Find on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-sun-ynu7j8?file=/src/components/FlightBooking.js)

It is more understandable when keeping the state variable as object since we can add/append/delete multiple keys in future.

You can use array as state as well, not much drawback in it, but it will have impact outside the reducer as well. Following encapsulation mechanism, that would be wrong.

```
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import { NEWBOOK, DELETEBOOK } from "./actionTypes";

const initialState = { myBookings: [] };

console.log(typeof initialState);
const bookingReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEWBOOK:
      return {
        ...state,
        myBookings: (state?.myBookings ?? []).concat(action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default bookingReducer;
```

Comment: `myBooks: state.myBooks.push(action.payload.bookObject),` will cause some problems. I guess you figured that out though since your sandbox code is different.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out. I just posted some sort of mechanism here and actual keywords were in the code sandbox.

Comment: `default: return { state };` will have the same/similar invariant mutation issue as OP's code where it nests the current state into a new object with `state` property, e.g. result next state will be `{ state: { myBookings: [.....] } }`.

Comment: Ok. It just needs to return back the state by **return state** or **return {...state}**

Comment: You could probably simplify the `NEWBOOK` case now that the `state.myBookings` sub-state isn't getting moved around, e.g. `myBookings: state.myBookings.concat(action.payload)`.